# Passing event and argument to v-on in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I pass a parameter in `v-on:input` directives. If I don't pass it, I can access the event in the method. Is there any way I can still access the event when passing the parameter to the function? Note that I am using vue-router.

This is without passing the parameter. I can access the event object:

HTML

```html
<input type="number" v-on:input="addToCart" min="0" placeholder="0">
```

Javascript

```js
methods: {
  addToCart: function (event) {
    // I need to access the element by using event.target
    console.log('In addToCart')
    console.log(event.target)
  }
}
```

This is when passing the parameter. I can't access the event object:

HTML

```html
<input type="number" v-on:input="addToCart(ticket.id)" min="0" placeholder="0">
```

Javascript

```js
methods: {
  addToCart: function (id) {
    // How can I access the element by using event
    console.log('In addToCart')
    console.log(id)
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle of the code, it should be good enough to replicate the problem that I am having:

https://jsfiddle.net/lookman/vdhwkrmq/

Answer (score 450, accepted):

If you want to access event object as well as data passed, you have to pass `event` and `ticket.id` both as parameters, like following:

**HTML**

```html
<input type="number" v-on:input="addToCart($event, ticket.id)" min="0" placeholder="0">
```

**Javascript**

```js
methods: {
  addToCart: function (event, id) {
    // use event here as well as id
    console.log('In addToCart')
    console.log(id)
  }
}
```

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nee5nszL/

### Edited: case with vue-router

In case you are using vue-router, you may have to use [$event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)  in your `v-on:input` method like following:

```html
<input type="number" v-on:input="addToCart($event, num)" min="0" placeholder="0">
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/raj11s4o/).

Comment: I tried but I get the error message `Property or method "event" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option`

Comment: @geckob you passed the event from HTML: `v-on:input` ?

Comment: Not sure this is related or not, but I am using vue-router and this happens in one of the partials

Comment: @Saurabh @geckob In order to avoid the error, you need to pass the special `$event` variable to the method call `v-on:input="addToCart($event, num)"`

Comment: You should pass `$event`, not `event`

Comment: These magic "special" $variables, bruh... Spent some time trying to figure out the type of it ;D The type is `Event` for fellow typescript users

Answer (score 52):

You can also do something like this...

```
<input @input="myHandler('foo', 'bar', ...arguments)">
```

Evan You himself recommended this technique in one post on Vue forum. In general some events may emit more than one argument. Also as [documentation states](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers) internal variable $event is meant for passing original DOM event.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/30115/

Note the spread syntax will be transpiled when using *.vue components, but not if you use in-browser compilation.

Comment: there is a difference between "...arguments" and "$event"?

Comment: @Raphael There is a difference! With "$event" argument you pass only one argument from the event.

Comment: this was the solution for me! Thanks

Comment: This solution works, unlike the other one. It does allow to pass multiple arguments as Raphael mentioned.

Answer (score 23):

Depending on what arguments you need to pass, especially for custom event handlers, you can do something like this:

`<div @customEvent='(arg1) => myCallback(arg1, arg2)'>Hello!</div>`

Comment: +1 though [always use kebab-case for event names](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names)

Answer (score 11):

I like this way of passing parameters because we can pass events and parameters both using an anonymous callback function.

```
<button v-on:click="(e)=>deleteHandler(e, args1)" > Click me </button>
```

Comment: You can also use the special `$event` variable for a shorter expression: `@click="deleteHandler($event, args1)"`.