# Draggable vue - how to access "column" id?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, drag-and-drop, dom-events, draggable

Right now I trying to use draggable to build a kanban (with four columns). I started creating two columns to learn about [vue-draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable), but I can't figure out how to access the column of task.

My first two columns:

```
<draggable v-model="myArray" class="simple-a" 
  :options="{group:'people'}" :move="onMove" 
  @start="changeDrag" @end="changeDrag" 
  @change="seeChange">
  <div v-for="(element, aIndex) in myArray" :key="aIndex" class="element-a">
      {{ element.name }}
    </div>
</draggable>

<draggable v-model="myArray2" class="simple-a" style="background:red;" 
  :options="{group:'people'}" :move="onMove" @start="changeDrag" 
  @end="changeDrag" @change="seeChange(1)">
  <div v-for="(element2, aIndex) in myArray2" :key="aIndex" class="element-a">
    {{ element2.name }}
  </div>
</draggable>
```

I am using `seeChange` function to get which element has changed:

```
seeChange({moved, added, removed}, col) {
  if(added){
    console.log(added);
    console.log('column: '+col);
  }
  if(moved){
    console.log(moved);
  }
  if(removed){
    console.log(removed);
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass col attribute to this function (change event), but I can't, is always `undefined`.

How can I pass an attribute to a change event of vue draggable ?
Or how is the correct/better way to get the new column of a edited item?

Comment: the change event only accepts the one argument so you'll have to use the newIndex and/or oldIndex (see [here](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events))

Comment: @LShapz something like that: `@change="seeChange(newIndex = 1)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you need to pass additional parameters to an event handler is

**template**

```html
<draggable ... @change="seeChange($event, 1)">
  ...
</draggable>
```

**component**

```js
methods: {
  seeChange(event, col) {
    console.log(event, col)
    ...
  }
},
```

Ref: [Passing event and argument to v-on in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956671/passing-event-and-argument-to-v-on-in-vue-js)