# How to operate DOM in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Here is the situation, I use v-for to display lots of data in JSON as seperate buttons. What I want to do is when i click single one of those buttons, the button's background color will change.
I want to use @click to bind function to each button, and in that function, do
as this

```
theButtonDOM.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
```

So, how can I get that DOM whose div element is generated by v-for?
OR any other solution to solve this 'background color change' problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you trigger a click event in Vue template, you can access the event adding the special variable $event as argument to the function.

```
<button @click="my_method($event, other_argument)"></button>
```

and then access the target of the event inside the method:

```
methods: {
    my_method(event, other_paramethers) {
        let button = event.target
}
}
```

Even just with bind the method to the `@click` event without any argument, you can access the event as your first argument.

```
<button @click="my_method"></button>
...
methods: {
    my_method($event) {
        let button = $event.target
}
}
```

Then you can play with your button.

Look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956671/passing-event-and-argument-to-v-on-in-vue-js) and [the Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `$event`

```
<button @click="changeColor($event)"></button>
```

Then in your method

```
this.changeColor = function(evt){ evt.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@click` and `v-bind:class`. When you click on an item, its index will be stored in `selectedItem`. Then `v-bind:class` automatically will add the class to the item that has an `index` equal to `selectedItem`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedItem: ""
  },
  computed:{},
  methods: {}
  }
)
```

```css
.selectedItemClass {
  background-color:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div v-for="(item,index) in ['aa','bb','cc']"
    v-bind:class="{  selectedItemClass : (selectedItem === index) }"
    @click="selectedItem = index"
  >{{item}}</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want the buttons to act as individual switches and not a [radio group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio), as implemented in the answer by @eag845.

---

You could add a 'clicked' boolean attribute to your JSON Objects.

```
arrayOfJSONObjects.forEach(object => object.clicked = false); // Add 'clicked' attribute and init to false
```

Then use that attribute as a conditional to bind a CSS class using `v-bind:class` or `:class`, and then toggle the attribute within `@click` or whatever event handler function you put inside `@click`.

```
<button
    v-for="btn in arrayOfJSONObjects"
    :class="{ 'button--activated': btn.clicked }"
    @click="btn.clicked = !btn.clicked"
>{{btn.foo}}</button>
```

Stylez

```
.button {
  background-color: white;
}
.button--activated {
  background-color: black;
}
```