# Vue : Custom parameter

Tags: vue.js

Let say `@on-change` default is return two parameters, so method `onChangeObserver` can direct assign like this.

```
<observer @on-change="onChangeObserver">
 <div class="test">TEST</div>.
</observer>

onChangeObserver(entry, unobserve) {
 console.log(entry.isIntersecting);
}
```

What if, I need third custom parameters, how can I do something like below

```
<observer @on-change="onChangeObserver(entry, unobserve, 'A')">
 <div class="test">TEST</div>.
</observer>

onChangeObserver(entry, unobserve, type) {
 console.log(entry.isIntersecting);
}
```

Comment: This syntax should work from the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59509133/872395
`@on-change="(entry, unobserve) => onChangeObserver(entry, unobserve, 'A')"`

Comment: Thanks ! It work ! Hard to find related question about this